# How do I move 2 csv files from my local machine to a remote machine (both are windows machines) ?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking for a one click solution like a vbs or batch file which would copy 2 csv files from my local machine to a remote server on a particular location. This is primarily what I'm looking for.

Also, I would like to know if the same is possible if my account is not added into the server users list (I don't have access). Is there some way by which just that particular location will be shared?

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: @Abdul - I used simple xcopy. Seems to be working fine. But for that to work, access to the remote server will have to be provided to the user triggering the job and the destination folder shared as well. Was wondering if there is a way by which this can be avoided!

Comment: Consider to use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)...

Comment: I'm looking to achieve this via Jenkins since it 'may' be possible to do the same as Jenkins uses SYSTEM account so even if the user isn't added to the server. Jenkins job might still be able to access it! But I havr almost zero knowledge about the same. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and share the specific folder on the server with your network. After that go to your client and open up the explorer. navigate to 'computer' and on the bottom you should find your network ressources. right click and add the server with his IP address. If done correctly you should have access to the servers folder as if it was one of your client. So you should now be able to create a desktop shortcut to the servers folder and be able to add files to the folder by drag & drop. Of course now you could write a simple batch file that copies all the contents of one of your folders to the servers folder.